# How do I get 64-bit binutils in Redhat 7

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

How do I check whether I have 32 or 64-bit binutils, and get 64-bit binutils, in RHEL 7 (my nm reports `nm: supported targets: elf32-i386 a.out-i386-linux srec symbolsrec tekhex binary ihex trad-core` and refuses to work on 64-bit .a files).

Answer (score 0):

you can check which package is installed with

```
rpm -q binutils
```

and explicitly append the architecture to the package-name when instlling using yum:

```
yum install binutils.x86_64
```